# masking with vertex groups in node editor - b3d 2.83

Tags: node-editor, vertex-groups

hello does someone know if its possible yet to use a vertex groups as a masks in the node/shader editor? i want to "procedurally" mask an area to get clean and sharp edges, because i tried to use a hand painted texture to mask the faces, but it pretty blurry and pixelated...

Comment: You can use Vertex Paint but its precision, therefore its sharpness, will depend on the topology of your object. Also, you should have good result with texture, why was it blurry?

Comment: too small res (2048 px) texture for a very small face loop (a sharp of a knife specifically)